# Why is Captain America described as the perfect human when he can be overpowered by people like the Hulk or Thor

Tags: marvel, comics, captain-america

How can Captain America be the 'perfect human' when:

- he can be overpowered by the Hulk
- isn't as agile as Spiderman
- is outmatched in intelligence by Reed Richards

He doesn't seem to be 'the best' at much in the Marvel Universe?

Comment: Led Luther? No wonder Superman has such problems with him. ;)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Captain America franchise, but where is it stated that he is the "perfect human"? And are you sure that was meant to be taken literally? I.e. sometimes people are referred to as the "perfect soldier" or the "consummate scholar/athlete/etc." simply as a figure of speech. That doesn't actually mean they are literally the absolute pinnacle of their profession or human potential in that regard.

Comment: Captain America in the Marvel Universe, is the pinacle of *human* potential. The other characters you describe, Thor the Hulk, Spiderman and Reed Richards Doctor Doom (I'm omitting Luthor and Braniac as those are both in the DC universe) are a Demi-god, and four Mutates,i.e. **not** human (anymore).

Comment: I got to get my universes right.

Comment: This *IS NOT* an opinion-based question. It may be badly worded, but has a definate answer. Those who voted 'on hold' should either attempt to edit the question, change the hold criteria or vote to re-open.

Answer (score 9):

Captain America isn't supposed to be the *Perfect Human*, but the **Perfect Soldier**.

His body has been accelerated to the maximum potential of human design (the human condition in the 20th Century, anyway), and as such he is still limited by the frailties and inherent weaknesses of a bipedal hominid.

His speed, agility, reflexes and muscle-mass have all been improved beyond that of any other man, *but he is still man*, unlike the other characters you have listed in your question.

[image: Hulk - Bruce Banner]

The Hulk undergoes a transformation that turns him into something distinctly inhuman, albeit human in origin, so whilst its tentative I don't think The Hulk is human, only Bruce Banner.

[image: Thor (movie depiction)]

As for Thor, it is overtly spoken in all his incarnations that he is **A GOD**, and as such is *not a human*, but an Asgardian. Whether people attribute the etymology of this to be alien or divine is down to individual interpretation, as comics have differed in their representation of this.

Marvel's [1602](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_1602) even has a minor storyline in which a monk discusses how Thor's existence is kept hidden by the Catholic Church (it is effectively the in universe Holy Grail) because of what he represents: proof of the existence of polytheism, meaning a range of different **Gods**.

As for Reed Richards?

[image: Reed Richards]

Whilst he is indeed a Human, I'm not sure he'd be able to best Cap in a fight. A battle of minds perhaps, yes, but Cap wasn't made to be a scientific genius but a *super soldier*.

Both men's minds where left unaltered by their transformation, it was only their bodies that were modified.

Pre-change, Reed Richards was a master scientist: his transformation only gave him the ability to manipulate his body.

[image: scene from the 2011 Captain America movie]

Steve Rogers, however, was *CHOSEN* for the super-serum project because he exhibited the perfect mental and behavioral characteristics for the perfect soldier. Namely:

- Bravery
- Obedience
- Intelligence
- Discipline
- And [selflessness](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kO6qu5fQLHo)

Steve Rogers already possessed the perfect mental characteristics to be America's ultimate weapon in the war against fascism... it was his body that was lacking.

The Super soldier program laced his body at the Apex of the human condition, but left him human nonetheless.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: A point about Reed Richards, he can stretch and manipulate the shape and size of his brain, thus giving himself super intelligence.  This is the explanation for his sudden leap in IQ in the Ultimate universe, and is the theory (but never definiativley stated) in the main 616 continuity.

Answer (score 5):

**In-universe:** Arguably, most of the other characters you mention are not human, so it's no contradiction that the would be more powerful.

As for human opponents: Maybe when people call Cap "the perfect human", they are simply exaggerating - or wrong? It's actually not even possible for a single human to be perfect in everything, especially in physical feats there are contradicting requirements. For example, it is impossible for one person to be both a top-level weightlifter and marathon runner because weightlifting requires you to maximize muscle mass, which is an active hindrance during long-distance running.

Additionally, it's always possible for circumstances to favor one combatant, or for one to be better prepared.

**Out of universe:** Comics are written by different authors, and expecting consistence in characters' powers is futile - a character will be exactly as powerful as the current author needs him to be for today's story. This is [magnified a hundredfold](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PowerCreepPowerSeep) in crossovers, since Cap getting smashed to pulp by the Hulk in under 1 second would be uninteresting as well as infuriate Cap's fans. So while that would be the realistic outcome given the established power levels, that story will not get written.